# How do I abstract a function with Selenium's `this.item.findElement()` into another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

I'm trying to set up a test with Selenium Webdriver and Cucumber.js on Node.js.

I have a check in a homePageSteps.js file to simply see if a banner exists on a page, eg:

```
Then('there should be a banner', async function() {
    var banner = await this.driver.findElement(By.className('banner')).getRect();
    assert.ok(banner.height!==null);
});
```

This works, but I was thinking it would be good see if I could extract this check to use on any steps file. So, I created a new file *banners.js*:

```
function checkBanner(driver) {
    var banner = this.driver.findElement(By.className('banner')).getRect();
    return banner.height;
  };

module.exports = { checkBanner };
```

And in my Cucumber steps file:

```
const banners = require("../../support/components/banners");

// Other things...

Then('there should be a banner', async function() {
  assert.ok(banners.checkBanner()!==null);
});
```

But of course this fails because the `banners.js` file has no knowledge of what page we are visiting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findElement')`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkBanner()` function should receive `driver` as an argument and then you should probably use `driver.findElement(...)` rather than `this.driver.findElement(...)`.

I would also suggest passing `By.className('banner')` as a second argument, so your helper can be valid for other banners with different locators ;)

```js
function checkBanner(driver, locator) {
  const banner = driver.findElement(locator).getRect();
  return banner.height;
};
```

Hope this helps!